# React table v8 - unable to change column size

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v8

I am using v8 and unable to change the width of the column of the most simple example.

https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/react/basic

Above is the basic example, I opened the sandbox and changed the size of the first column to 500, as below:

```
columnHelper.accessor('firstName', {
  cell: info => info.getValue(),
  footer: info => info.column.id,
  size: 500,
  minSize: 500
}),
```

However the width of the first column remain unchanged, any idea?

Figure: How the table looks before & after adding the size property:
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/TanStack/table/issues/5115#issuecomment-1780496617
Width needed to be binded explicitly to work